# Outlook 2010 stuck on "Loading Profile" for terminal server users

Tags: exchange-2010, rdp, outlook-2010

We've got a Server2008R2 functioning as a terminal server.

Users attempting to open Outlook10 on this server get stuck at "Loading Profile"

Sometimes a username\password field will come up after about 25-30 seconds, filling it out correctly can result in Outlook opening properly 20 seconds later, or a "Server not found, work offline?" window.  Sometimes hitting Retry will force Outlook to open.

Sometimes rebooting the server fixes the issue, sometimes it does not.

Any help?

Comment: Is the outlook on the terminal server set to use cached exchange mode? Can you turn it off and see if you get the same results?

Comment: I seem to remember reading somewhere that cached exchange mode should not be used on terminal servers, all of our users should be using online mode

Comment: Ok, there are a couple of things I would check. is outlook anywhere enabled in exchange? Have you tried wiping out the user profile and re creating it?

Comment: Outlook Anywhere is enabled, and works like a charm internally and externally, just not on the TS. Wiping out a user profile doesn't seem to have an effect.  I've created a few test users and had Outlook autodiscover their settings on the TS, I've also manually configured Outlook, same result.

Comment: So with outlook anywhere disabled you get the same result?

Comment: Do you mean from the exchange farm?  I haven't tried that, I suppose I could give it a go late-night tonight, I've got a bunch of users working from home using Outlook(not through the TS, just locally from their laptops) so I can't really test it right now.

Comment: Sorry, I meant locally on the Outlook client. You can disable it there. It will re-enable after you restart outlook but it is good for testing.

Comment: Disabled from Outlook produces similar results :/

Comment: Well I am out of ideas. I would verify that your TS is not dropping any packets from your exchange farm.